# Java App for Mirroring Windows Screen to Anycast Device

Tags: java, sockets, screen, mirror, hdmi

I recently used [AirMyPC](http://www.airmypc.com) as a paid software for having a mirroring windows screen (laptop) to my real TV.

B'coz my TV already plugged with this **Anycast (hardware below)** device so this software work smoothly.

[image]

I wonder if i could make the same app using java programming.
I completely followed the java socket tutorial nicely until connecting two laptop for a chat purpose. And found out for making the similar mirroring feature is using the same concept as usual java socket. Because java socket is a communication between two port client & server,

So how about this anycast device? 
Which port is opened once my laptop already connected to its device IP?

CMIIW. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenTV Player SDK by Google. They have both an android and java version of the SDK. Honestly, I have not used it. But that is where I would start.